# Vue.js even numbered rows formatting

Tags: vue.js

Using vue.js I am trying to to make odd rows with a class of light-orange and even rows with a class or green

In my template, I have

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="m in menu">\
    <div class="menu-item light-orange">{{#if Math.abs($index % 2)}}\
                            <a href="#feature-modal" data-toggle="modal">\
                                <i class="fa {{m.icon}}"></i>\
                                <p>Feature</p>\
                            </a>\
                        </div>\
                        </div>\
```

In addition to the Math.abs there, I tried a few other math related functions... all with the same result... ie. Always showing the text in the if statement

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Vue.js does not support mustache template syntax. That is why the `if` statement is showed up in the page.

Instead, Vue has a special class binding [`v-bind:class`](https://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) or in short `:class` that can be used to set the element's classes by passing expressions:

```
<div :class="{'light-orange': $index % 2 === 0, 'green': $index % 2 !== 0 }">
  ...
</div>
```

If the expression is truthy, the class name will be added, otherwise it will not.

---

Regarding the `if` statement, there is also a [`v-if`](https://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-if) directive which handles the presence of an element in the DOM.

It takes an expression and will add the element into the DOM if the expression evaluates to a truthy value.

In some cases we might need to have an `else` statement, and that is what [`v-else`](https://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-else) directive is for.

It's worth noting that the element having a `v-else` directive must follow the `v-if` element immediately within the template.

Comment: Awesome... thanks alot. I know it was simple, but skipped my mind. Thank you for the input

Comment: in Vue 2.x : `for (m, index) in menu` and then use `index`

Comment: in vue 3.x v-for="(m, index) in menu" :key="index" then use index without dollar sign in above example.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use css.

```
.menu-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
} 

.menu-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed it with Tailwind CSS. So no need to use vue' conditions Here's a solution:

```
<table>
  {#each people as person}
    <tr class="bg-white odd:bg-gray-100 ...">
      <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
  {/each}
</table>
```

Doc: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#odd