# Vue3 dynamic classes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus

I want to give dynamic or different classes to different rows of an element plus table. Basically, I want to give different colors to each row. I want to iterate an array that has colors in it for example

```
const colors = ["blue","yellow","black"]
```

I have tried binding this to my row like this:

```
<el-table-column prop="owner">
          <template #header>
            <span class="title">所有者</span>
          </template>
          <template #default="scope">
            <div class="owner">
              <div :class="colors">
                {{ scope.row.owner.slice(0, 1) }}
              </div>
              <div>{{ scope.row.owner }}</div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
```

But, it is not iterating through the array and gives only one class to all of the rows.
This is the CSS for classes:

```
.blue {
  background-color: rgb(125, 125, 216);
}
.yellow {
  background-color: rgb(164, 164, 71);
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Hope this explains my question, should I attach the full code for reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354482/vue-js-even-numbered-rows-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose one color based on the row index mod 3 :

```html
<div :class="colors[scope.$index % 3]">
```

Comment: It works, thank you. A question, where is the $index coming from? is that a vue thing?

Comment: You're welcome, it specific to element like `scope.row`, please check this https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html#custom-column-template